# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, in react hooks crud application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-hooks, crud

I'm working on a simple crud application with React.js and I'm having this issue: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when I try to display the list of the events that I get from : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events (which shows the list of events in json format).

Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Event from './Event';
import axios from 'axios';

class DisplayEvent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '', events: '' };
  }
  onDelete = id => {
    // console.log("event list ", id);
    this.props.onDelete(id);
  };

  onEdit = id => {
    // console.log("event list ", id);
    this.props.onEdit(id);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ events: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  };



  render() {
    const events = this.props.events;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Events</h1>




        <table className="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td>
              <td>Event Name</td>
              <td>Event Description</td>
              <td width="200px">Actions</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {events.map(event => {
              return (
                <Event
                  key={event.id}
                  event={event}
                  onDelete={this.onDelete}
                  onEdit={this.onEdit}
                />
              )
            })}

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default DisplayEvent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set `events` to an empty array on the state
2. Read the events from the state instead of props:
3. (Optional) use `loading` state to show a loader and determine when the data has been fetched.

```
class DisplayEvent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '', loading: true, events: [] }; // use array here
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ events: response.data, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({loading: false});
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { events, loading } = this.state; // get events from the state
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Events</h1>
        <table className="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td>
              <td>Event Name</td>
              <td>Event Description</td>
              <td width="200px">Actions</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {loading ? (
              <p>Loading events...</p>
            ) : (
              events.map(event => {
                return <Event key={event.id} event={event} onDelete={this.onDelete} onEdit={this.onEdit} />;
              })
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi again @Clarity I'm getting this error now: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: If you got in the `catch`, change it to arrow function ```.catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({loading: false});
      });```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `state` rather than `props` since you set the API response to your `state`

```
  render() {
    const { events } = this.state;
    ...
```

Comment: Honestly state and props are still confusing for me, thanks! I changed the code as you mentioned and it says : TypeError: events.map is not a function

Comment: @AlaBenAicha Then you may need to check whether the state is an Array or not

Answer (score 1):

Set an empty array to `events` if the data returned by API is `undefined`. Right now you have not added a condition to handle that scenario. If you get an `undefined` value from response which is not an array, that why it is showing this error.

```
        this.setState({ events: response.data || [] });
```

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ events: response.data || [] });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  };
```

**UPDATE**

```
const events = this.props.events || [];
```

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned and it still returns :  TypeError: events.map is not a function

Comment: I have updated the answer. You still need to check if it is not an array, assign an array value, please check the updated answer.